# javascript object key value giving undefined even its defined

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

when i am trying to reach malzeme.aciklama im getting this error:

```
model.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aciklama')
    at model.js:33:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Module.loadDisplay (model.js:20:11)
    at async controlDisplay (controller.js:10:5)
```

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "malzeme": {
        "id": "1",
        "malzeme_id": "1",
        "locale": "tr",
        "aciklama": "STRN-50M 1/2 HP, Monofaze",
        "fiyat": "314.00",
        "deleted_at": "13.09.2022 14:37",
        "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "stok_kodu": "0111STRN50M"
    },
    "stok_kodu": "0111STRN50M",
    "aciklama": "",
    "fiyat": ""
}
```

my code:

```
dataWeb.forEach(element => {
    let newObj = {
      id: '',
      malzeme: '',
      stok_kodu: '',
      aciklama: '',
      fiyat: '',
    };
    newObj.stok_kodu = element.stok_kodu;
    newObj.id = element.id;
    let malzeme_id =
      dataLogo[
        dataLogo.indexOf(dataLogo.find(item => item.malzeme_id === element.id))
      ].aciklama;

    newObj.malzeme = malzeme_id;
    newArray.push(newObj);
  });
```

object key and value as output defined but when im trying to reach in foreach loop its giving undefined

Comment: How is `dataLogo` populated? It is unable to find `element.id` in `dataLogo`. Also, `dataLogo[dataLogo.indexOf(dataLogo.find(...))]` is same as `dataLogo.find(...)`

Comment: `dataLogo.find()` is probably returning `null` because it's not finding a matching `malzeme_id`. Then `indexOf()` returns `-1`, and that index of `dataLogo` doesn't exist.

Comment: Is this ES6 + HTML?

Comment: {
    "id": "5001",
    "malzeme_id": "5606",
    "locale": "tr",
    "aciklama": "Ergonomik Seperatör Gerdiricisi",
    "fiyat": null,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "stok_kodu": "14643"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the json you gave above, how to get malzeme.aciklama is just by this:

`newObj.malzeme = element.malzeme.aciklama;`

first because `element.malzeme` isn't array. if it's an array, then you have to initialize first the `dataLogo` to that array.
`let dataLogo = element.malzeme`
then you can iterate and find the element by using same id and get the aciklama